# Proving that If $\overline K \trianglelefteq \overline G$ , then $\phi^{-1}(\overline K)=\{k\in G: \phi(k)\in\overline K\}\trianglelefteq G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from group $G$ to group $\overline G$. It is to be proven that if $\overline K$ is a normal subgroup of $\overline G$, then $\phi^{-1}(\overline K)=\{k\in G: \phi(k)\in\overline K\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I tried to prove it as follows: 
Suppose on the contrary that $\phi^{-1}(\overline K)$ is not normal to $G$. This means that $\exists x\in G$ such that $xk\ne k'x \;\;\forall  k, k'\in \phi^{-1}(\overline K)$. This implies that $xkx^{-1}\notin \phi^{-1}(\overline K)$ for any $k$ in $\phi^{-1}(\overline K) $.$\tag{1}$
But $\phi(xkx^{-1})=\phi(x)\phi(k)(\phi(x))^{-1}\in\overline K$ as $\overline K\trianglelefteq \overline G$, which contradicts $(1)$

Is my proof correct? Thanks for your time.